# Show that all the conics o tangential in $[1,0,0]$ on the line $x_1=0$, is a 3D subspace of $\mathbb{P}(Sym_{\mathbb{R}}(3))$

Tags: matrices, conic-sections, projective-geometry, projective-space, symmetric-matrices

How to show that all the conics on $\mathbb{P^2}=\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{R^3})$, tangential in $[1,0,0]$ on the line $x_1=0$, is a 3-dim subspace of $\mathbb{P}(\operatorname{Sym}_{\mathbb{R}}(3))$? Where $\mathbb{P}(\operatorname{Sym}_{\mathbb{R}}(3))$ is the projective of the vector space of the symmetric matrices $3 \times 3$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Count degrees of freedom.